# serverspec test fails to check if Docker service is running on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-ami, packer, serverspec

I'm using Packer to create an AMI in AWS based on the Amazon Linux AMI, provisioned with Ansible.

Some of my serverspec tests fail and I don't understand why. First one that always fails is trying to make sure that Docker is installed and running. It always fails trying to test that the service is enabled and running. This is my spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe package('docker') do
  it { should be_installed }
end

describe service('docker') do
  it { should be_enabled }
  it { should be_running }
end
```

After googling a bit, I've tried this with same results

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe package('docker') do
  it { should be_installed }
end

describe service('docker') do
  it { should be_enabled.with_level(2) }
  it { should be_enabled.with_level(3) }
  it { should be_enabled.with_level(4) }
  it { should be_enabled.with_level(5) }
  it { should be_running }
end
```

While provisioning with Ansible, I've tried to execute the same commands that serverspec is using for the specs, and I get what I understand is the right answer, but still specs fail.

These are the commands that serverspec is using

```
amazon-ebs: 2) Service "docker" should be enabled with level 2
amazon-ebs: On host `localhost'
amazon-ebs: Failure/Error: it { should be_enabled.with_level(2) }
amazon-ebs:   expected Service "docker" to be enabled with level 2
amazon-ebs:   /bin/sh -c chkconfig\ --list\ docker\ \|\ grep\ 2:on
amazon-ebs:   
amazon-ebs: # ./spec/localhost/docker_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
amazon-ebs:
amazon-ebs: 3) Service "docker" should be enabled with level 3
amazon-ebs: On host `localhost'
amazon-ebs: Failure/Error: it { should be_enabled.with_level(3) }
amazon-ebs:   expected Service "docker" to be enabled with level 3
amazon-ebs:   /bin/sh -c chkconfig\ --list\ docker\ \|\ grep\ 3:on
amazon-ebs:   
amazon-ebs: # ./spec/localhost/docker_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
amazon-ebs:
amazon-ebs: 4) Service "docker" should be enabled with level 4
amazon-ebs: On host `localhost'
amazon-ebs: Failure/Error: it { should be_enabled.with_level(4) }
amazon-ebs:   expected Service "docker" to be enabled with level 4
amazon-ebs:   /bin/sh -c chkconfig\ --list\ docker\ \|\ grep\ 4:on
amazon-ebs:   
amazon-ebs: # ./spec/localhost/docker_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
amazon-ebs:
amazon-ebs: 5) Service "docker" should be enabled with level 5
amazon-ebs: On host `localhost'
amazon-ebs: Failure/Error: it { should be_enabled.with_level(5) }
amazon-ebs:   expected Service "docker" to be enabled with level 5
amazon-ebs:   /bin/sh -c chkconfig\ --list\ docker\ \|\ grep\ 5:on
amazon-ebs:   
amazon-ebs: # ./spec/localhost/docker_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
amazon-ebs:
amazon-ebs: 6) Service "docker" should be running
amazon-ebs: On host `localhost'
amazon-ebs: Failure/Error: it { should be_running }
amazon-ebs:   expected Service "docker" to be running
amazon-ebs:   /bin/sh -c service\ docker\ status
amazon-ebs:   
amazon-ebs: # ./spec/localhost/docker_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And this is the playbook that installs Docker, printing the output of the same commands as serverspec uses

```
---

- name: Install yum dependencies
  yum: name=docker state=present

- name: "Starting Docker service"
  service: name=docker enabled=yes state=started

- command: "chkconfig --list docker"
  register: docker_enabled

- debug: var=docker_enabled

- command: "service docker status"
  register: docker_status

- debug: var=docker_status
```

And the output of both commands are

```
    amazon-ebs: TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
    amazon-ebs: ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    amazon-ebs: "stdout": "docker         \t0:off\t1:off\t2:on\t3:on\t4:on\t5:on\t6:off",
    amazon-ebs: }
    amazon-ebs:

    amazon-ebs: TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
    amazon-ebs: ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    amazon-ebs: "stdout": "docker (pid  2943) is running...",
    amazon-ebs: }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your playbook and spec are both fine, which means something on the backend/OS/dependencies/etc. is at fault here. Try investigating in that direction.

Comment: Don't know what else to investigate, since those commands have the right exit code when I run them. Any idea?

Comment: Amazon Linux on AWS